# Identity of two differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Today I've encountered [this proof of Euler's Formula](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Formula#Direct_Proof_1). The proof basically says that $e^{iz}$ and $(\cos z + i \sin z)$ are both solutions of the differential equation $f'(z) = i f(z)$ and do not differ by a constant.

Everything is clear to me, however I have a doubt: isn't it necessary to demonstrate that if:

$$
f'(x) = k f(x) \\
g'(x) = k g(x)
$$

Then $f' = g'$? If so, how can I proceed to build a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What was given in that link is that: when $f'=g'$ we know that $f=g+C$ wherein $C$ is any constant. Now, if we consider an initial condition [for example if $z=0$ then $e^{iz}=e^{i\times 0}=1$ and $\cos(0)+i\sin(0)=1$]; then we get $C=0$.

Comment: Fine, but my question is: how do we know that $f' = g'$?

Comment: If $f=\exp(iz),~g=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$ then $f'=i\exp(iz)=i\times[\cos(z)+i\sin(z)]=i\cos(z)-\sin(z)=g'$

Comment: But where is the proof for $i \exp(iz)= i\times[\cos(z)+i\sin(z)]$?

Comment: @heyhey: This exactly what you noted above. In fact according to the link both are solutions of the ODE and then they satisfy the same OE as you asked above. I mean $f'=if$

Comment: I get your point. Probably my question isn't much clear. I'll try to rephrase it: how do we know that the solutions to the ODE are unique? (Or, to be more precise, they differ by a constant?)

Comment: @heyhey: If you want this point, Michalis gave you the exact and corretc link. Indeed the picard's theorem help us to know whether the solution is unique or not.

Comment: + 1, again. And another (if I could) for sportsmanship!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

To show $f=g$ you can use the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: In fact you did it here. +1